# Summing different columns and returning array for chart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an article model (which belongs to a user) and holds the number of `facebook_shares`, `linkedin_shares` and `twitter_shares`. I'd like to sum the number of facebook/linkedin/twitter shares for each user's articles and return them into an array I can put into a chart.

This is how I'm currently doing it, returning the results in a `=content_tag` as per this [Railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts-graphs-revised?view=asciicast):

```
 = content_tag :div, "", id: "shares-chart", data: {shares: 
   [
     {y: 'Tweets', a: @user.articles.sum(:twitter_shares)},
     {y: 'Facebook', a: @user.articles.sum(:facebook_shares)},
     {y: 'LinkedIn', a: @user.articles.sum(:linkedin_shares)}
   ]
  }
```

But this seems like an ugly way. Is there a nicer way using .map? It's a function I can't figure out how to apply to columns, rather than records.

Comment: Where are you using this code? can you give us a context? The way you put it simply seems like a json.

Comment: Hi, sorry about that, it's being returned into the data parameter for a chart. I will move it out into a helper most likely, but I'd like to understand the best way to make the query first. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think that is a better way. The part ` @user.articles.sum(:linkedin_shares)` seems optimal.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! However, I felt that the answer below was closer to what I wanted - it just seems a bit cleaner.

Comment: cool,thanks for letme know when you found an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want this:

In your `User` model:

```
def construct_data
  [{"Tweets" => :twitter_shares}, {"Facebook" => :facebook_shares}, {"LinkedIn" => :linkedin_shares}].map do |h| 
    {y: h.keys.first, a: @user.articles.sum(h.values.first)}
  end 
end
```

In your controller action:

```
@chart_data = @user.construct_data
```

In your view:

```
 = content_tag :div, "", id: "shares-chart", data: {shares: @chart_data}
```

Comment: Ah yes - this seems much cleaner. It does the same number of DB queries, but at least it's more concise (and keeps the code out of the view). Note - I had to pass parameters into the model to stop it throwing a nilclass exception (so `@chart_data = @user.construct_data(@user)`) but otherwise it functions perfectly. Thanks!